# Interpreting Dbeaver Transaction log

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, dbeaver

I need help debugging a database availability incident that coincided with an ALTER TABLE statement that was executed on a high(-ish) traffic table.

I used Dbeaver 23.1.5 to login to our primary production database server(RDS, db.m6g.2xlarge, us-east-1) on a write-permitted connection. I then executed a routine DDL update to a SQL table. Seconds after executing the statement, I manually committed the transaction. Around the same time a bunch of applications that depend on the database simultaneously went into an availability incident. Number of 5xx responses went through the roof for about 20 mins before resolving by itself. An RDS metric - DBLoadNonCPU - spike was observed as well-
[image: DBLoadNonCPU metric spike]

My top theory is that I took a waited too long between executing the statement and committing the transaction. This may have led to the transaction holding on to the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock for long enough that queries from application workloads starting timing out and thrashing. Is there any way I can verify this was the case? I am attaching a screenshot from the Dbeaver Transaction log dialog below. It shows two entries for the statement in question - first at 15:30 which coincides with the start of the incident and the second at 15:50(the apps recovered about 20 mins later).

[image]

1. Are there any other logs(Dbeaver, Postgres, Cloudwatch) that can be used as supporting evidence?
2. From the evidence provided, is my thought process on the right track?